# How to move bootstrap 3 carousel caption below images?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have this html that shows slideshow images using bootstrap 3 :

```
<div class="col-sm-8">



            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                {% for p in posts %}
                    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                    <div class="item active">
                    {% else %}
                    <div class="item">
                   {% endif %}

                    {% if p.headimage %}
                    <img src="{{ p.headimage.url }}" alt="Image" width="460" height="345">
                     {% endif %}
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>{{ p.title }}</h3>
                        <p>{{ p.teaser }}</p>
                      </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>

</div>
```

I want caption to be shown below the image, not over it.

I tried to manipulate the html and css but could not achieve this, so appreciate your help.

Update: Apart from native bootstrap, I have tried these custom css directives (which did not help):

```
.carousel-inner { padding-bottom:95px; }
.carousel-caption { bottom:-95px; }
```

Comment: I found this very useful for pushing the content below on smaller screens.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Start by changing the position of the caption element from `absolute` to `relative`:

```
.carousel-caption {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5htqu7y9/)**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#homeCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
  });
});
```

```css
#carouselButtons {
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.carousel .carousel-caption {
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.carousel .carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Menu -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <!-- Item 1 -->
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1800x600" />

      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Bootstrap 3 Carousel Layout</h1>

          <p>This is an example layout with carousel that uses the Bootstrap 3 styles.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com">Learn More</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Item 2 -->
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1800x600" />
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>

          <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Item 3 -->
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1800x600" />
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Percentage-based sizing</h1>

          <p>With "mobile-first" there is now only one percentage-based grid.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This also works for Bootstrap 4 in case you got here.

Comment: Perfect answer. Works also on the Lottie animation inside the carousel.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where I wanted the caption to be overlaid on the image on a large screen, and below the image in smaller sizes. I made overflow in .carousel-inner visible. I believe this would be a helpful, alternate way to position the caption text outside of the bound of the carousel images itself regardless of whether its part of a responsive element or not.

Edit: You must also change the height of the carousel (the containing div, not "inner") to accommodate the height of the image plus the caption.

```
.carousel-inner{
overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: This causes the hidden elements to be shown (eg. the hidden slides) during animation.