# How to keep carousel-indicators on image while carousel-caption below image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

[How to move bootstrap 3 carousel caption below images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125830/how-to-move-bootstrap-3-carousel-caption-below-images)

I incorporated the above solution into my code so now I have the text (carousel-caption) below the images in the carousel. However, doing this also moved the arrows in the carousel-control.left and carousel-control.right further down. It also positioned the carousel-indicators to below the carousel-caption. As a result, when the amount of text changes, the carousel-indicators and left/right controls move to adjust for the change in text.

This is not ideal, and I would like the carousel-indicators and left/right controls to remain on the image, while the carousel-caption is below.

Thanks!

Comment: The carousel-controls can be fixed by moving them after / outside the carousel-inner div (in the html), but I myself and still searching how to fix the carousel-indicators.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use absolute positioning to move you carousel indicators dynamically

```
.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%
    left: 150%;
    z-index: 15;

    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}
```